# Filter list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my example:

```
dictlist = [{'first': 'James', 'last': 'Joule'}, 
            {'first': 'James','last': 'Watt'},
            {'first': 'Christian','last': 'Doppler'}]
```

I am trying to get the last name. If this was in a model, the code would be:

```
getdata = Name.objects.filter(name="Christian")
getLastName = getdata.last
```

and I would get `"Doppler"`.

Comment: [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) allow optional filtering with `if`.

Answer (score 21):

This is very simple solution with list comprehension:

```
>>> dictlist = [{'first': 'James', 'last': 'Joule'}, {'first': 'James','last': 'Watt'},{'first': 'Christian','last': 'Doppler'}]
>>> [x['last'] for x in dictlist if x['first'] == 'Christian']
['Doppler']
```

Comment: That is what I had in mind at first, but this results in a list with a single string, which I don't think is optimal.

Comment: Yeah that's true I suppose, +1

Answer (score 10):

```
dictlist = [{'first': 'James', 'last': 'Joule'}, {'first': 'James','last': 'Watt'},{'first': 'Christian','last': 'Doppler'}]
the_jameses = [d for d in dictlist if d['first'] == 'James']
```

Where the resulting `list` contains only:

```
[{'first': 'James', 'last': 'Joule'}, {'first': 'James', 'last': 'Watt'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

To start with, we can have a simple script that just uses the built-in [python filter method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), and this might already be sufficient:

```
fl = list(filter(lambda x: x['first'] == 'Christian', dictlist))

# you can't use `.property` because this is a dictionary, not a object
fl[0]['last']
# returns Doppler
```

I realize your example is a Django code, so if you want to make this more dynamic so that you are able to filter by any key in the dictionary:

```
def dict_filter(dictlist: list, key: str, value: str) -> list:
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.get(key) == value, dictlist))

dict_filter(dictlist, 'first', 'Christian')
# similar to django's filter method returns a queryset, this returns a list:
# [{'first': 'Christian', 'last': 'Doppler'}]

dict_filter(dictlist, 'last', 'Doppler')
# returns [{'first': 'Christian', 'last': 'Doppler'}]

dict_filter(dictlist, 'last', 'notfound')
# returns []
```

And an example to use [python filter method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to create a similar function to Django's `QuerySet.get` method:

```
def dict_get(dictlist: list, key: str, value: str) -> list:
    ret = list(filter(lambda x: x.get(key) == value, dictlist))
    if len(ret) == 0:
        raise Exception('Not Found')
    if len(ret) > 1:
        raise Exception(f'Found more than 1 object with {key}={value}')
    return ret[0]

dict_get(dictlist, 'first', 'Christian')
# returns {'first': 'Christian', 'last': 'Doppler'}
    
dict_get(dictlist, 'first', 'Christians')
# raises Exception: Not Found

dict_get(dictlist, 'first', 'James')
# raises Exception: Found more than 1 object with first=James
```

Hope this is helpful to you!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
last_name = ''

for d in dictList:
  if d['first'] == 'Christian':
    last_name = d['last']
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes like to use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```py
next((d['last'] for d in dictlist if d['first'] == 'Christian'), None)
# 'Doppler'
```

The first argument is an iterator and the second (optional) argument is the default value returned if no matching entry is found.

**Note:** this will only return the first matching result. So it wouldn't be good if you expect to have multiple records matching your "query".

Answer (score -3):

**Hope this is helpful to you!!**

```
"; my_dict=[
{
    'username':"Siva",
    'phoneno':"12345678915",
    'city':"Chennai"
},
{
    'username':"Sundhar",
    'phoneno':"12345678917",
    'city':"Vellore"
},
    {
    'username':"cockroach",
    'phoneno':"12345668919",
    'city':"Chennai"
},
    {
        'username':"oggy",
        'phoneno':"12345678917",
        'city':"Chennai"
    }
]

";phoneno="12345678917"
```

result = [user['username'] for user in my_dict if user['phoneno']== phoneno]

Comment: What is even going on in this answer? Why did you add the `";` later?

Answer (score -4):

```
for comp in dictlist:
    if comp["first"] == 'Christian':
        return comp["last"]
```

Comment: `dictlist` is a `list`, not a `dict`.