# How to filter array with particular ID in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a list of output that are append from my web scraping.

```
for post in get_posts("test", pages=50):
    print(post)
    listposts.append(post)
```

---

Actual output:

```
{'post_id': '1', 'text': 'abc'}
{'post_id': '2', 'text': 'haha'}
{'post_id': '3', 'text': 'abc'}
{'post_id': '4', 'text': 'haha'}
```

---

How can make it to show only `text with abc` ? :

Expected output:

```
{'post_id': '1', 'text': 'abc'}
{'post_id': '3', 'text': 'abc'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474022/filter-list-of-dictionaries)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `if` condition in your loop to conditionally append to your `listposts` list

```
for post in get_posts("test", pages=50):
    print(post)
    if "abc" in post["text"]: 
        listposts.append(post)
```

use `if post["text"] == "abc":` for exact match

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it keep returning me the same value inside the listpost when i print it out [Image](https://ibb.co/mGS6xqf)

Comment: @johnny2000 can't help more with what you tell me